# Calling miktexsetup.exe succeeds interactively but fails from batch file

Tags: miktex, windows

When I call `miktexsetup.exe` at the Windows Command Prompt, it behaves as expected and succeeds. But if I put it into a batch script, it fails with the output

```
installed 3706 package manifests
visiting repository \\fra-app-216\miktex...
repository type: local package repository
loading package repository manifest...
MiKTeX encountered an internal error.
Info:
Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\Core\Session\config.cpp
Line: 577

Sorry, but "MiKTeX Configuration Utility" did not succeed.
initexmf: MiKTeX encountered an internal error.
```

Executed command is `\\server\miktex\miktexsetup.exe --verbose --trace --local-package-repository=\\server\miktex --modify-path=yes --package-set=essential --shared=no --use-registry=yes --user-roots="<LOCALAPPDATA>\texmf" install`

What goes wrong here?

**Debug Details**

Using the DebugView utility which receives the `--trace` messages I tried to investigate further, but I fail to understand cause of the problem. Last log output of the failed attempt is:

```
[miktexsetup.setup]: Installation: C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9  
[miktexsetup.setup]: initexmf "--user-install=C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9" --set-config-value=[Core]SharedSetup=0 --user-roots=<LOCALAPPDATA>\texmf "--log-file=C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex/config\uninst.log" --disable-installer --verbose:    
[miktexsetup.core]: redirecting stdout to a pipe    
[miktexsetup.core]: make child stderr = child stdout    
[miktexsetup.core]: setting env MIKTEX_GS_LIB=C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\ghostscript\base;C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\ghostscript\base;C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\fonts;C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\fonts 
[miktexsetup.core]: setting env MIKTEX_CWDLIST= 
[miktexsetup.core]: start process: initexmf "--user-install=C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9" --set-config-value=[Core]SharedSetup=0 --user-roots=<LOCALAPPDATA>\texmf "--log-file=C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex/config\uninst.log" --disable-installer --verbose   
[miktexsetup.core]: setting env MIKTEX_EXCEPTION_PATH=C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\mik6A21.tmp  
[miktexsetup.core]: start reading the pipe  
[miktexsetup.core]: read 170 bytes from the pipe    
[miktexsetup.core]: parsing: C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\mik6A21.tmp...    
[miktexsetup.core]: setting env MIKTEX_EXCEPTION_PATH=
```

where the successful attempts shows an `initexmf` call and reads 76 butes from the pipe:

```
[miktexsetup.core]: setting env MIKTEX_EXCEPTION_PATH=C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\mikA665.tmp  
[miktexsetup.core]: start reading the pipe  
INFO  initexmf - starting: MiKTeX Configuration Utility 2.9.7251 (MiKTeX 2.9.7250 64-bit)   
INFO  initexmf - Operating on the private (per-user) MiKTeX setup   
INFO  initexmf - starting with command line: initexmf "--user-install=C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9" --set-config-value=[Core]SharedSetup=0 --user-roots=<LOCALAPPDATA>\texmf "--log-file=C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex/config\uninst.log" --disable-installer --verbose     
INFO  initexmf - Registering root directories...    
INFO  initexmf - Setting config value: [Core]SharedSetup=0  
INFO  initexmf - finishing with exit code 0     
[miktexsetup.core]: read 76 bytes from the pipe
```

and goes on with the installation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if it is still the same problem, but after updating the repository today (which pulled MiKTeXsetup 2.9.7000 MiKTeX 2.9.7250), the error message changed to:

```
Configuration error: cannot convert '--verbose' to boolean.
Info: s="--verbose"
Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\Core\Session\config.cpp
Line: 574
```

which is considerably more helpful. Removing the option `--verbose` did the trick. No error anymore.